# Magento Catalog Search (filter by id)

Tags: php, search, magento, module

I'm writing a custom plugin thing which needs to search the product catalog.  Based on some sample code I saw somewhere (possibly this site), I came up with this working prototype:

```
$searcher = Mage::getSingleton('catalogsearch/advanced')
   -> addFilters(array('name' => $_REQUEST['name']))
   -> addFilters(array('sku' => $_REQUEST['sku']))
;
$products = $searcher->getProductCollection();
```

This works great for those two fields, but I also need to search by product id.  It seems like the proper field to search on is 'entity_id', but its not working:

```
$searcher->addFilters(array('entity_id' => $_REQUEST['id']));
```

I've also tried using 'product_id' and simply 'id' with no luck.  Keep getting this error:

> Mage_Core_Exception: You have to
>   specify at least one search term

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?  Maybe I should be using a different class to do my searching?

Comment: If you have an id could't you just try to load a product instead of retrieving a collection?

Comment: In the code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/controllers/AdvancedController.php file the search is called like this:

    Mage::getSingleton('catalogsearch/advanced')->addFilters($this->getRequest()->getQuery());

What happens if you enter the id directly in the call?

    Mage::getSingleton('catalogsearch/advanced')->addFilters($id);

Comment: It needs to be searchable by any of those 3 fields.  I can't use $this->getRequest()->getQuery() because I'm doing it outside of a controller.  Tried doing ->addFilters($id) with no luck.

But you did give me a great idea - since there is only ever 1 product with a given ID, simply load that product in.  Otherwise, do the search using the other two fields.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Jimmy for your help!  Turns out I was overthinking things.  I've implemented an **if** statement to simply load by id (if provided), otherwise do the search.